# Angular Firebase retrieve Timestamps as Date

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I´m currently running an Angular project with Firebase as a serverless backend.
There are two main models in the application `user` and `product`. Both of these models have several different timestamps such as `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `lastPurchase`, ...

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    displayName: string;
    lastPurchase?: Date;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

```
interface Product{
    id: string;
    title: string;
    pricing: number;
    category: string;
    user: User;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

The problem is that I´m working with the `Date` type, but Firebase deliveres stored dates like this `t {seconds: 1584540876, nanoseconds: 300000000}`.
Therefore, I´m forced to convert all incoming Firebase timestamps to JavaScript `Date` types. Additionally, since Firebase´s Firestore is a NoSQL Database, I can never be certain which document contains which timestamp properties (for null checks).

This is the current working code I use when retrieving data from Firestore, but it is quite a mess.

```
    // Iterate over all properties in product
    for (let key in data) {
      // Check if property is an object
      if (data[key] instanceof Object) {
        // Check if the object is Firebase Timestamp
        if (data[key].constructor.name === 't') {
          const property: string = key;
          console.log(data[key]);
          data[key] = data[property].toDate();
          // Check if property is an user
        } else if (key === 'user') {
          // Iterate over all user properties
          for (let userKey in data[key]) {
            // Check if user property is an object and the object is Firebase Timestamp
            if (data[key][userKey] instanceof Object && data[key][userKey].constructor.name === 't') {
              const userProperty: string = userKey;
              data[key][userKey] = data[key][userProperty].toDate();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there an alternative solution / method to achieve this with less computation?

Comment: Not really.  You're doing the right thing.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the reply. I´m not really experienced with measuring performance, so do you think this block of code could be a huge performance problem when doing it for each incoming doc?

Comment: What you're doing has essentially no observable cost at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to display the date, simply use the date pipe of angular.

```
<div>{{user.updatedAt.toDate() | date: 'medium'}}</div>
```

Date pipe has other option like full, short also.

You can use firebase timestamps to store the date. You can use them like this:

```
import { firebase } from 'firebase/app';
import Timestamp = firestore.Timestamp;

interface User {
    id: string;
    displayName: string;
    lastPurchase?: Timestamp;
    createdAt: Timestamp;
    updatedAt?: Timestamp;
}
```

Then, when you update them you can do so using now function:

```
User.update({
    updatedAt: Timestamp.now();
})
```

This will save updatedAt at the time when you can the function to the update. You can similarly update createdAt and other dates.

Comment: I thought about this solution but didn´t implement it this ways because of two reasons:

1) I don´t want to make my app fully dependent on Firebase, so I can swap out the backend if needed.
2) I couldn´t find a way to add Timestamp as a global type without having to add the import every time.

Comment: You can create the timestamp using "new Date().getTime()"

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same problem and finally found this solution.
set

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    displayName: string;
    lastPurchase?: MyDate;
    createdAt: MyDate;
    updatedAt?: MyDate;
},
```

and next create class MyDate

```
export class MyDate {
  seconds: number;
}
```

and in You code set this

```
<div>{{user.updatedAt.seconds * 1000 | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</div>
```

Comment: So, you are basically just storing the seconds in the database?

Comment: Basically yes, this idea has occurred to me when I see how I receive data from firebase, in the database they are represented by date and time, but data received is seconds and nanosecond. With this I stop worrying if the date is correct or not.